# How to get the number of requests over a configurable time period for a panel only

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I want to be able to see the number of requests created within a certain period of time (e.g. the last [5m], [1h], [6h], [1d]).

Is it possible to create a variable in Grafana which can be applied only to the panel (individual chart dropdown), and not to the entire dashboard (not the global filter at the top)?

Have a query `increase(requests_total[5m])` - "5m" should be replaced by variable.

- it is necessary to see the number of requests for a configurable time interval
- it is possible to select a date (for example, yesterday) at the top right of the dashboard and also specify an interval for the number of requests (for example, the last 5 minutes), so `$__interval` can't be used
- the interval should be specified only for one dashboard panel since there are other panels that do not depend on this filter

As an alternative to the dropdown list for a specific panel, I can create additional queries or even separate panels for the intervals [5m], [1h], [6h], [1d]. But it will look cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

You can define how many "interval variables" you need and use them in each panel you wish:

[image]

See more details in Grafana documentation [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/variable-types/add-interval-variable/).